# Pure javascript slider bar limit

Tags: javascript

Im working with 3 slider bars with max=100 min=0, the first one its the principal, the other two bars value can't be higher or equal than the first one, and the third one value can't be higher or equal than the second one.
I dont know if it's there an operator or function to do that, to limit the value between a min max range.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Foundations
<input type="range" name="s1" min="0" max="100"  id="bar1" value="0" oninput="mover1();">

</div>
<div>
Walls
<input type="range" name="s2" min="0" max="100"  id="bar2" value="0" style="margin-left: 1.9em;" >

</div>
<div>
Roof
<input type="range" name="s3" min="0" max="100" id="bar3" value="0" style="margin-left: 2.7em;" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should value be adjusted only when first `<input type="range">` value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script>
    var ranges;
    window.onload = function() {
      ranges = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=bar]");
    }

    function mover1() {
      if (+ranges[1].value >= ranges[0].value) {
        ranges[1].value = +ranges[0].value - 1
      }
      if (+ranges[2].value >= ranges[1].value) {
        ranges[2].value = +ranges[1].value - 1
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Foundations
    <input type="range" name="s1" min="0" max="100" id="bar1" value="0" oninput="mover1();">

  </div>
  <div>
    Walls
    <input type="range" name="s2" min="0" max="100" id="bar2" value="0" oninput="mover1();">
    <!-- style="margin-left: 1.9em;" -->
  </div>
  <div>
    Roof
    <input type="range" name="s3" min="0" max="100" id="bar3" value="0" oninput="mover1();">
    <!-- style="margin-left: 2.7em;" -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the `max` property of a slider to the `value` property of the previous slider. If you do this for all (except the first) sliders at any change of any of them, you'll have the desired effect:

```js
var sliders = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'));
sliders.forEach( slider => slider.addEventListener('change', updateSliders));

function updateSliders() {
    sliders.reduce( (prev, curr) => {
        curr.max = prev.value - 1;
        return curr;
    });
}

// Optionally show the value next to the slider:
var values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.value'));
sliders.forEach( slider => slider.addEventListener('change', displayValue));

function displayValue() {
    sliders.forEach( (curr, i) => values[i].textContent = curr.value );
}
displayValue();
```

```html
<table><tr>
    <td>Foundations</td>
    <td><input type="range" name="s1" min="0" max="100" id="bar1" value="0"></td>
    <td class="value"></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Walls</td>
    <td><input type="range" name="s2" min="0" max="100" id="bar2" value="0"></td>
    <td class="value"></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Roof</td>
    <td><input type="range" name="s3" min="0" max="100" id="bar3" value="0"></td>
    <td class="value"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: @guest271314, that surprises me. I cannot make that happen. You have some trick?

Comment: Must be browser dependent then. in Firefox the second value never gets passed the first. I also tried in Chrome and Edge, and also there it is not possible to break the rule.

Comment: All this is not happening in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, the browsers I tested this with. This looks like a chromium thing. True when you put the second slider in the middle and then change the first slider, the second one will move, but not its value (in Chrome, Edge, Firefox), unless it gets out of range, then it is adjust to the max value.

Comment: Tested on Chrome version 56 and 57. The issues you mention do not occur.

Comment: Strange, is all I can say. I see that your solution has a different approach and does not use the max attribute, but reduces the area where the slider can be put. My solution was to reduce the max attribute and leave the whole visible range available. Maybe that is the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *second range is moved programmatically*. When changing the value of the first, only the `max` property value of the second is adapted. This can have a visual effect (re-scaling), but it does not change the `value` property of the second range (unless it would become out of range). Too bad my solution got the impression of somehow not being correct, while I believe it was. :-(

Comment: But the visual effect is not about the `value`. In your comments you wrote *"increasing value of first range decreases value of second range"*, but the **value** of the second range was not decreasing at all. The visual position is not the same thing as the value. Sure, the visual effect is expected, since the min-max range of the slider changes. It is like that in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div>
    Foundations
    <input type="range" name="s1" min="0" max="100"  id="bar1" value="0" oninput="mover1();" onchange="changeOne();">

    </div>
    <div>
    Walls
    <input type="range" name="s2" min="0" max="100"  id="bar2" value="0" style="margin-left: 1.9em;" onchange="changeTwo();">

    </div>
    <div>
    Roof
    <input type="range" name="s3" min="0" max="100" id="bar3" value="0" style="margin-left: 2.7em;" >
    </div>

       <script>  
        var bar1 = document.getElementById("bar1");
        var bar2 = document.getElementById("bar2");  
        var bar3 = document.getElementById("bar3"); 
            function changeOne()
            {

                bar2.setAttribute("max", bar1.value);
                bar3.setAttribute("max", bar2.value);
            }

             function changeTwo()
            {

                bar3.setAttribute("max", bar2.value);
            }

            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```